Extend it downward/below
[Suppose while making a drawing, a student draws a (10 cm long) vertical line, and the teacher wants him to increase its length by 5 cm in the downward direction]

Extend it (=the line) below by 5 cm.

Extend it downward by 5 cm.

Extend it further downward by 5 cm.

Extend it further down by 5 cm.


Are these sentences correct?

Extend the line by 5 cm.

@Lambie - upward(s) or downward(s)?

Extend it down by 5 cm.

Oh yeah, extend the line down or up by 5 cm. My main point was about by.

Is the use of "below", as an adverb, incorrect in (1)?

I’d choose down as suggested by Weather Vane and Lambie.  It is accurate and concise.  Ngram shows that extend it down is more common than the downward and my added downwards versions.
The further down version is not found.  The word further is redundant and would make clumsy this case and the  further downward one.  The below version
isn’t applicable here as it needs a reference point.

+1 for the first paragraph.  If the teacher wanted the student to draw a perpendicular line, the teacher might say "Not there. Place the perpendicular line further down."

Thanks, @TimR.  Yes, further down would be appropriate in a case like placing a new line below some points currently looked at.
